# Java unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 netbeans {"copy", "169"}, // ? - copyright sign

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding

I've downloaded the apache lang source, but my netbeans encoding is UTF-8, I gen an error that:

```
\src\org\apache\commons\lang\Entities.java:64: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
        {"copy", "169"}, // ? - copyright sign
```

how can I solve this?

I've tried to encode the file itself to utf-8 by notepad++ but it didn't helped

Answer (score 1):

Try with the unicode symbol : "\u00a9".

You should not use special char directly in code, use code dedicated for this instead to avoid this kind of problems.

Edit : Using the class you mentionned in comment, you can use

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(yourCharacter);
```

That will return your character (in your case copyright) as html code (`&copy`). If you want to do the reverse treatment, you can use

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(yourCode);
```

That will return for example the copyright sign if you pass `&copy` as parameter.

Comment: Savard the problem is that I've downloaded apache commons https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html - to use this class, but I've gotted this error...its version 2.6, the newer version doesn't have this class,

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want, but check my edit it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for netbeans IDE

1.Right click on the apache lang source project and select

```
->Properties
  ->Sources
    ->Bottom left click the encoding drop down list and select ISO 8859-1
```

2. Delete the following classes

```
 org.apache.commons.lang.Entity
 org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
```

Remember if you decide to go with the first solution then this will change the encoding of your project.
if you want to maintain your project encoding as the default UTF-8 then use the second solution but this means you lose out on StringEscapeUtil functionality.